# How to automaticaly plot multiple numerical functions?

Tags: plotting, numerics

I am new to Mathematica and I don't understand how can I plot more numerical functions on the same graph without writing them manually. I don't think that I explain what I do to clearly but I will attach some pictures below in hope of making it easier to understand.

```
xM = 20; 
Nx = 1024; 
dx = 2xM / Nx; 
m=1;
\[HBar]=1;
\[Omega] =1;
\[Alpha]=Sqrt[m \[Omega]/\[HBar]];
X = Table[-xM + i * dx, {i,1,Nx}];
\[Phi][n_,x_]=Sqrt[\[Alpha]/(2^n n! Sqrt[\[Pi]])]HermiteH[n, \[Alpha] x]E^(-\[Alpha]^2 x^2/2);
ListLinePlot[{Table[{X[[i]],Abs[\[Phi][1,X[[i]]]]^2},{i,1,Nx}]},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->Automatic]
ListLinePlot[{Table[{X[[i]],Abs[\[Phi][2,X[[i]]]]^2},{i,1,Nx}]},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->Automatic]
ListLinePlot[{Table[{X[[i]],Abs[\[CapitalPhi][j][[i]]]^2},{i,1,Nx}],{j,1,2}},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

This is the code that I used, and the last part is what I have trouble with. The function doesn't really matter, I just used the wavefunction of the harmonic oscilator.

[image: This is the image that I get from the first 2 plots, and also the ones that I want on the same graph]

[image: And this is what I am getting from the last line.]

Comment: You have not included the definition for `\[CapitalPhi]`

Comment: I just notice it after you told me. In Mathematica I saw just the symbols and I didn't realised I used the CapitalPhi instead of the normal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do this:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[Phi][1, X[[i]]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}],
  Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[Phi][2, X[[i]]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}]
  }, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

If so, you could do this:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[Phi][j, X[[i]]]]^2}, {i, 1, Nx}], {j, 1, 
   2}]
 , PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

or this:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{X[[i]], Abs[\[Phi][j, X[[i]]]]^2}, {j, 1, 2}, {i, 1, Nx}], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

You have a typo (and using capitial phi instead of small phi) in your last and the {j,1,2} is sitting outside the table.

You are probably better off using SetDelayed in your function
[Phi][n_,x_]:= .... instead of what you have which is [Phi][n_,x_]= ....